Mathematica gives zero for non-zero double integral?
Consider the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, \frac{1}{(xy+i)(x+y-i)^2},$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit. I can evaluate this integral analytically using residue calculus (or Mathematica). For the inner integral I get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{1}{(xy+i)(x+y-i)^2} = \begin{cases} \frac{-2\pi i y}{(-i+y(y-i))^2} \quad & y > 0 \\ 0 \quad & y \leq 0\end{cases}.$$
The remaining integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}  dy  \frac{-2\pi i y}{(-i+y(y-i))^2} $$
can be evaluated analytically in Mathematica and gives approximately
1.70277 + 0.729469 I

However when I evaluate the double integral
Integrate[1/((x*y + I) (x + y - I)^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

analytically in Mathematica it gives
0

Why is this?

Sometimes it does not handle multiple integrals nicely because it fails to use the GenerateConditions apparatus on inner integrals. Workaround: `In[7]:= Integrate[1/((x*y + I) (x + y - I)^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -In
finity, Infinity}, GenerateConditions->True]
30     16 I
Out[7]= (-(---) + ----) Pi ((-8 - 2 I) + Sqrt[1 - 4 I] Pi +
289    289
1

 (2 I) Sqrt[1 - 4 I] ArcTanh[-------------])


                               Sqrt[1 - 4 I]

In[8]:= N[%]
Out[8]= 1.70277 + 0.729469 I`

I see. So probably it takes the value 0 for the inner integral, i.e. the y < 0 value, so that the remaining integral is trivially zero?

I didn't check the run in detail but I think it is more or less as you suggest. It got an unconditional result on the y integral that should really be conditional, and very likely it is an odd function of x so the next integral is (as you anticipated) trivially 0.

Check the limits on your double integral.  They don't match the limits on the single integrals.

@LouisB I don't think so. Note that the x-integral is zero if y < 0, so the y integral is really from 0 to infinity.

@DanielLichtblau I think it really evaluates the inner integral as zero unconditionally, when it should be evaluating it to zero only under the condition that y < 0.

$$4 \pi  \left(\frac{1}{4+i}-\frac{1}{8-15 i} \sqrt{1-4 i} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-4 i}\right)\right)$$
4 π (1/(4 + I) - 1/(8 - 15 I) Sqrt[1 - 4 I] ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - 4 I]])
